# Server Sent events only sending static data - Flask

Tags: flask, server-sent-events

As an example, consider the below example.

This, works.

```
@app.route('/api/v2/push-notifications', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def publish_server_event():
      event = "1234-event"
      def event_stream(event):
         yield "event: "+event+"\ndata: test\n\n"
      return Response(event_stream(event), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

This does not work...

```
    @app.route('/api/v2/push-notifications', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def publish_server_event():
      event = request.form['event']
      def event_stream(event):
         yield "event: "+event+"\ndata: test\n\n"
      return Response(event_stream(event), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Problem is when I try to calculate something, the event is not received at the front end inside `source.addEventListener`. If I pass the value directly or through a variable, considering that it's static, it works.

Comment: In the second code sample, have you tried `event = request.form['event']` followed by `print (event)` to ensure that's set to what you expect?

Comment: @v25 Yes. The value inside request.form['event'] is "1234-event"